# Is there a tool to know which DLLs are running a website in IIS

Tags: iis

Just like we have SQL Profiler tool which gives us info as what SPs, queries are running in SQL Server

Similarly i want to know is there a tool for IIS so that i can know which DLLs are being used while i run my website in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg and SOS will help you out:

> [Investigating ASP.Net Memory Issues using WinDbg and SOS](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060114.asp)

Here are a couple of great resources on using WinDbg, SOS and ADPlus:

> [If broken it is, fix it you should (Tess Ferrandez)](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/default.aspx)
>   [Speaking of Which (Johan Straarup)](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/tags/WinDbg/default.aspx)